# GCC/Clang vs. MSVC: Missing Wconversion warning in template function with std::invoke

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm encountering an issue where a template function uses `std::invoke` to call another function, passing a `size_t` argument to a parameter expecting an `int32_t`. This should, theoretically, trigger a warning about type conversion. However, when compiling with GCC or Clang using the `-Wconversion` flag, no warning is issued, whereas MSVC correctly reports a warning.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```cpp
void expectsInt32(int32_t) {
    /* … */
}

template<typename Func, typename Arg>
void call(Func func, Arg arg) {
    std::invoke(func, arg); // arg is size_t, potentially causing narrowing conversion
}

int main() {
    size_t largeNumber = 4294967295; // Maximum value for uint32_t
    call(expectsInt32, largeNumber); // Compiles without warning in GCC/Clang with -Wconversion
    return 0;
}
```

On MSVC, this code triggers a warning about the potential data loss during the conversion from size_t to int32_t:

```
C:/data/msvc/14.39.33321-Pre/include\type_traits(1739): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
C:/data/msvc/14.39.33321-Pre/include\type_traits(1739): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
C:/data/msvc/14.39.33321-Pre/include\type_traits(1739): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(18): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void call<void(__cdecl *)(int32_t),size_t>(Func,Arg)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Func=void (__cdecl *)(int32_t),
            Arg=size_t
        ]
<source>(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::invoke<void(__cdecl *&)(int32_t),Arg&,>(_Callable,_Ty1) noexcept(false)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Arg=size_t,
            _Callable=void (__cdecl *&)(int32_t),
            _Ty1=size_t &
        ]
Compiler returned: 2
```

However, the same warning is not emitted by GCC or Clang, even with the `-Wconversion` flag enabled.

Why might GCC/Clang not warn about this implicit conversion in the context of `std::invoke` with template arguments? Is there a way to enforce such warnings or add static assertions to catch these cases at compile time?

Here's the code reproduced on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/KPPYM8cna

Comment: Even adding the more explicit `-Wshorten-64-to-32` doesn't generate a warning (but with or with that, a warning is given for a *direct* call: `expectsInt32(largeNumber);`. Weird.

Comment: You can use `-Wsystem-headers` with gcc. See [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43167).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to enforce such warnings

Yes, with gcc you can use flag `-Wsystem-headers` along with `-Wconversion` to enable such warnings. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4j7o9nnrj)

The warnings are suppressed here because they happen in a **system header**.

There is a confirmed gcc bug for the same:

[Warnings should not be disabled when instantiating templates defined in system headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43167)